# Separator Template for table building repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have built repeaters before but dont have much experience manipulating table layout with them. Presently I have a repeater that is populating the data correctly but doing so in one column. I would like it to be 4 columns. I was told using a Separator Template is the best way to do this.

Here is my repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myTestRepeater" runat="server"    
onitemdatabound="myTest_ItemDataBound">             
<Itemtemplate>
   <table cellpadding=0 width="100%" valign="top">
     <tr>
       <td valign="top" width="100%">
         <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkTest1" runat="server">
            <asp:Image ID="imgTest" runat="server" /></asp:HyperLink>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkTest2" runat="server" />
            <asp:Label ID="lblCounter" runat="server />
            <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkTest3" runat="server"/>
       </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a literal as a table break. Then populating that literal based off the mod of my counter

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myTestRepeater" runat="server"    
onitemdatabound="myTest_ItemDataBound">             
<Itemtemplate>
<table cellpadding=0 width="100%">
 <tr>
   <td valign="top" width="25%">
     <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkTest1" runat="server">
        <asp:Image ID="imgTest" runat="server" /></asp:HyperLink>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkTest2" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblCounter" runat="server />
        <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkTest3" runat="server"/>
   </td>
   <asp:literal id="tablebreak" runat="server"></asp:literal>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then code behind

```
Literal tableBreak = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("tablebreak"); 
if (e.Item.ItemIndex % 4 == 3)
    tableBreak.Text = "</tr><tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The repeater is the most powerful control in the ASP.NET WebForms arsenal; you just need to think sometimes on what is the best way to use it.

For example, you can have a repeater to make multiple rows, and a repeater to make multiple columns. In your situation, if you want your repeater to make multiple columns, you can easily adapt your code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
        <tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <td>
             <span>This will be repeated for each element</span>
         </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

It's all in basically how you want to implement your loop.

Comment: you need to remover `<tr>` from header and `</tr>` from footer and put it in itemtemplate tag, your code will render all data in one row!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Seperator Template is used to define the separator between rows. Why can't you use four `<td/>`s for your four columns?

```
<Itemtemplate>

     <tr>
       <td>
           ...
       </td>
       <td>
           ...
       </td>
       <td>
           ...
       </td>
       <td>
           ...
       </td>
     </tr>

</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="myRepeater">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Col 1
            </td>
            <td>
                Col 2
            </td>
            <td>
                Col 3
            </td>
            <td>
                Col 4
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table></FooterTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="background-color: #E1E1E1">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way this may be accomplished following the repeater control conventions.

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptTest" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
                <td>
                    <asp:Literal ID="litContent" runat="server" />
                </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
            </tr>
            <tr>
    </SeparatorTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The code-behind:

```
int counter = 0
  , columnCount = 3;

rptTest.ItemDataBound += (rpt_sender, rpt_e) => {
    if (rpt_e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || rpt_e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
        string cellData = (string)rpt_e.Item.DataItem;
        Literal litContent = (Literal)rpt_e.Item.FindControl("litContent");

        litContent.Text = cellData;
    }
    else if (rpt_e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Separator) {
        if (++counter % columnCount != 0)
            rpt_e.Item.Visible = false;
    }
};

rptTest.DataSource = new string[] { "Cell 1", "Cell 2", "Cell 3", "Cell 4", "Cell 5", "Cell 6", "Cell 7", "Cell 8", "Cell 9", "Cell 10" };
rptTest.DataBind();
```